# Loop Optimization in C

Tags: c, loops, optimization

I have been tasked with optimizing a particular for loop in C. Here is the loop:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000
#define N_TIMES    600000

for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++)
{
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
    {
        sum += array[j];
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to use loop unrolling, loop splitting, and pointers in order to speed it up, but every time I try to implement something, the program doesn't return. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) 
{
    int j,k;

    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) 
    {    
        for (k = 0; k < 100; k += 2) 
        {
            sum += array[k];
            sum += array[k + 1];
        }
    } 
}
```

I don't understand why the program doesn't even return now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a debugger. I would leave the compiler do the optimizations. I guess it is some homework! And the second program is not the same as the first, you are summing the `array` only up to 101 in the second case.

Comment: Your new program's run time is about 100x the original.

Comment: @T.C. I would say about 50x the original as k counter increase by 2 per loop.

Comment: @Sky I would say about 100x as it does `sum += ` twice...

Comment: Not what you asked, but you can eliminate the outer loop entirely. And in the inner loop just have sum += array[j] * N_TIMES; Now you can use pointer arithmetic for a little more performance with sum += *array++ * N_TIMES;

Comment: @ring0 oh yes I didn't notice about that, I was only focusing on the loop counts.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor the pointer arithmetic version may be worse, many CPUs have instructions designed to index a base by an offset

Comment: TBH the best answer is probably to take a modern compiler, put it on maximum optimization level and see what assembly it generates

Comment: @MattMcNabb, it would be interesting to see, my guess is that at full optimization there will actually be very little difference if any in the assembly generated, simply because this is such a straight forward piece of code. But I have not checked...

Comment: You mentioned that you are using a DSP.  Most DSPs, now a days, have an internal loop mechanism.  Your best bet is to modify your code to fit within the internal loop mechanism.  That would effectively eliminate all but the first(setup) instruction fetches and the trailing instruction fetches.   That would be my goal for optimization.

Comment: On most DSPs, there is a unroll pragma, that you can use so no actual changes in your code.

Comment: One very good optimization is to force the data to be properly boundary aligned (a pragma).  This will greatly reduce the number of data fetch operations performed.

Comment: Using the register attribute on the loop counters and on the sum value would almost completely eliminate the repetitive loads/saves to/from the stack of those variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That second piece of code is both inefficient *and* wrong, since it adds values more than the original code.

The loop unrolling (or lessening in this case since you probably don't want to unroll a ten-thousand-iteration loop) would be:

```
// Ensure ARRAY_SIZE is a multiple of two before trying this.
for (int i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 2)
        sum += array[j] + array[j+1];
```

But, to be honest, the days of dumb compilers has long since gone. You should generally leave this level of micro-optimisation up to your compiler, while you concentrate on the more high-level stuff like data structures, algorithms and human analysis.

That last one is rather important. Since you're adding the same array to an accumulated sum a constant number of times, you only really need the sum of the array *once,* then you can add that partial sum as many times as you want:

```
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    temp += array[i];
sum += temp * N_TIMES;
```

It's still `O(n)` but with a much lower multiplier on the `n` (one rather than six hundred thousand). It *may* be that gcc's insane optimisation level of `-O3` could work that out but I doubt it. The human brain can still outdo computers in a lot of areas.

For now, anyway :-)

Comment: Thank you. I understand that compilers will do most of the work these days, but the assignment requires that I use these optimization techniques to speed things up. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @user3698112: then submit something similar to the second code segment. You'll blow the other submissions out of the water and probably also blow the hat off your educator :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo the second for loop is a simple multiplication sum = temp * N_TIMES;

Comment: @Manül: yes, how very silly of me. Modified to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: If you're going to unroll, fix the "loop carried dependency" by summing into two separate accumulators, then add them at the end:  `sum1 += array[j]; sum2 += array[j+1];`  Otherwise the unrolling doesn't really accomplish much.

Comment: @Peter, that's a good idea if your intent is to try and do some automated parallelism but unrolling can have _other_ benefits distinct from that (for example, not continuously branching back to the loop start as much). Unless automated parallelism is available, summing to two accumulators instead of one won't have much benefit. Of course, it's possible I may have misunderstood your comment. If so, let me know.

Comment: @paxdiablo The parallelism comes from multiple issue at the hardware level.  Even inside the loop, the microprocessor can compute multiple additions in the same cycle.  But not if they all need to sum into the same location: then each iteration depends on the results of the previous.  That's what's called a "loop carried dependency".  Doing this with an unrolling factor of 4 buys me an extra 20% on my hardware.

Comment: @Peter, without _knowing_ the target hardware, coding for parallelism is probably not worth it. However, I'll add a note incorporating your comment when I get to a non-mobile device with a decent keyboard :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong on your program... it will return. It is only going to take 50 times more than the first one...

On the first you had 2 fors: 600.000 * 10.000 = 6.000.000.000 iterations.

On the second you have 3 fors: 600.000 * 10.000 * 50 = 300.000.000.000 iterations...

Comment: There's fifty times the number of loops but each loop also does twice the workload. So the _time_ takes will probably be about a hundred times as long.

Comment: Yes, that's why i used the word iterations and not operations... by iterations I meant the number of comparisons/increments for the variables that control the loops only...

Comment: Ah, I see, I looked only at the "take 50 times more" and assumed that was time. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Loop unrolling doesn't speed loops up, it slows them down. In olden times it gave you a speed bump by reducing the number of conditional evaluations. In modern times it slows you down by killing the cache.

There's no obvious use case for loop splitting here. To split a loop you're looking for two or more obvious groupings in the iterations. At a stretch you could multiply `array[j]` by `i` rather than doing the outer loop and claim you've split the inner from the outer, then discarded the outer as useless.

C array-indexing syntax is just defined as (a peculiar syntax for) pointer arithmetic. But I guess you'd want something like:

```
sum += *arrayPointer++;
```

In place of your use of `j`, with things initialised suitably. But I doubt you'll gain anything from it.

As per the comments, if this were real life then you'd just let the compiler figure this stuff out.

Comment: You can _partially_ unroll a loop and still stay within code cache bounds. Not sure if the effect is worth it though, given how fast the cache is. But you're right, in a system that caches code, unrolling a 10000-iteration loop may well make things worse.

Comment: @paxdiabli possibly true, but your expanded loop is more likely to push something else out of the cache, especially if it starts near a page boundary. But on the other hand your branch predictor is quite possibly running the next iteration _while_ it evaluates the condition putting you back to no benefit. All cutting back to the issue that these are highly architecture-dependant trade offs, best left to the architecture-specific compiler.